# SQL average Percentage by group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table1 with some sample record (would have more than 100 records)

```
lastname    courtesy    
Lane          3  
Lane          4  
Lane          5  
Lane         12   
Santana       4  
Santana       5
```

My query to get the ave percent group by lastname and did not group by lastname
you can see Lane and Santana still not group.
Please correct the query. Thank you.

```
SELECT
  lastname,
  courtesy,
  percentage = AVG(courtesy) * 100 / SUM(AVG(courtesy)) OVER (PARTITION BY lastname)
FROM echo
GROUP BY
  lastname, courtesy
```

the results

```
lastname    courtesy    percentage
Lane         3           12
Lane         4           16
Lane         5           20
Lane         12          50
Santana      4           44
Santana      5           55
```

the results look like this

```
lastname    percentage
Lane         16        (4/24)
Satana       22        (2/9)
```

```
count (lastname) / sum (courtesy)  group by lastname
```

Comment: Because you say group by with 2 column and courtesy have distinct data

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: so any work around?

Comment: Remove courtesy and view result, then edit answer and write your need result.

Comment: What are you expected results here exactly?

Comment: Can you explain what is 16 and 22?

Comment: count (lastname) / sum (courtesy)  group by lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the logic that you want:

```
SELECT lastname,
       SUM(SUM(courtesy)) OVER (ORDER BY lastname),
       COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(courtesy)
FROM echo
GROUP BY lastname;
```